# Magento: Get product id by url

Tags: php, magento-1.8

For example, here is url

> http://www.tiffosi.com/mulher/camisas-e-tunicas/blusa-l-s-93368.html.

There are several simple products. How can I get the actual simple product ID, from this url?

**Magento 1.8**

Answer (score 1):

First use the URL rewrite model to find the route which matches your product:

```
$vPath = 'http://www.tiffosi.com/mulher/camisas-e-tunicas/blusa-l-s-93368.html';
$oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->loadByRequestPath($vPath);
```

Then you can call getProductId() on the route to locate the produc's id:

```
$iProductId = $oRewrite->getProductId();
```

Finally if you require the product model object itself it's then a simple matter to call:

```
$oProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($iProductId);
```

Comment: how can we get it in magento 2